# Problemas con Apache Cordova y generacion de APK que se envia al telefono ( mediantre Drive o Whatsapp )

Tags: android, apk, apache-cordova

tengo generado el apk con apache cordova, estoy usando la ultima version , la 12 , que tambien viene con la version 12 de cordoba-android.
Estoy generando el build , cuando lo mando al teléfono, funciona bien , cuando lo genero como apk , lo firmo y lo mando por adb , tambien funciona bien , pero cuando me lo mandó a un drive o por whatsapp, me dice que no se puede instalar la app , alguno le paso algo similar,
Estoy haciendo todo esto con una app de helloworld, porque con la app principal me hacia lo mismo.